# How to add an <ol> and </ol> to my array?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

How would I be able to print my array to the page using an ordered list? For example:

```
var arrayName = ['String1','String2','String3'];

String 1
String 2
String 3
```

Comment: You'll need to let us know what you have tried, post the relevant code and/or a JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var arrayName = ['String1','String2','String3'];

var newOrderedList = $('<ol/>');

for(var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++){
    newOrderedList.append('<li>' +arrayName[i]+'</li>');
}

$('body').append(newOrderedList);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adg75dza/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var string = '<ol>';    
foreach(i in arrayName){
 string = string + '<li>' + arrayName[i] + '</li>';
}
string = string + '</ol>';

document.write(string);
```